# how to resolve the issue vertx-maven-plugin not found?

Tags: maven, reactive-programming, vert.x

I have below pom.xml , but am facing issue with plugin "vertx-maven-plugin" and it is saying that vertx-maven-plugin not found , any help please .

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.jponge.javamag-rxjava-vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-samples</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- vert.x properties -->
        <vertx.version>3.5.0</vertx.version>
        <vertx.verticle>samples.MainVerticle</vertx.verticle>
        <!-- Maven plugins -->
        <vertx-maven-plugin.version>1.0.13</vertx-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
                <artifactId>vertx-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${vertx.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vertx-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>vmp</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>initialize</goal>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <redeploy>true</redeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please show the full error output...

Comment: that is the error , it is not able to find that plugin , is their any issue with that pom.xml

Comment: Please add the error output which is presented in the console ......

Comment: vertx-maven-plugin has been migrated, try using the most recent version -> <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
                <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.18</version>

Answer (score 1):

You're using a very old version of the plugin. This should do the job. For more information refer to the documentation at https://reactiverse.io/vertx-maven-plugin/

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.18</version> 
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>vmp</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>initialize</goal>
        <goal>package</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <redeploy>true</redeploy>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```